# Get XML file with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I save following XML code as XML file.

```xml
<Z>
  <F>{"attributes":{"type":"form"}}</F>
  <M><%@ taglib prefix="zf" uri="http://www.zcore.org/tags/form" %></M>
</Z>
```

now when I want to load with JQuery I get this error :

> Timestamp: 5/5/2013 7:05:13 PM
>   Error: not well-formed

and this for the `<%@ ... %>` syntax that I put in the XML file.

How can I read this file as XML file without error?

Thanks to All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your values in [CDATA blocks](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) so that the XML parser ignores the inner text. See below:

```
<Z>
  <F><![CDATA[{"attributes":{"type":"form"}}]]></F>
  <M><![CDATA[<%@ taglib prefix="zf" uri="http://www.zcore.org/tags/form" %>]]></M>
</Z>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your XML to be well formed. Check it using an online validator 
http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. 
It says:

> The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

in other words you have to encode the `<%@ ... >` value as `&lt;` and `&gt;`